# Where`s this in Monts-Valin National Park?

Tags: identify-this, quebec

I lighted on [this website](https://www.rivercitygranitestl.com/lac-st-jean-mapa) that contains [the picture beneath](https://www.dreamstime.com/stock-photo-monts-valin-early-autumn-parc-national-des-dominates-landscape-saguenay-lac-saint-jean-region-quebec-canada-image69477344) titled 'Monts-Valin in early autumn' by [Zhao Qin](https://www.dreamstime.com/ssawpics_info) in Montreal QC.

1. Please see the titled question.
2. Can I drive to it in a rental sedan?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, you should contact the person who took the picture and ask him about it (where he took it).

From what I can see the photo looks to be taken from the Mirador:

https://www.sepaq.com/resources/docs/pq/mva/mva_guide_visiteur.pdf

Second, this is in the Parc national des Monts-Valin (Provincial Park).

You can get to the park entrance by regular car and if going in winter, you will need winter tires.

After that, I'm not certain, your best bet is to get good walking shoes.